# sudo command with equal sign (=) gets confused for environment variable

Tags: linux, shell, sudo

I'm trying to run various commands through *sudo*, where the equal sign (*=*) is a part of the command. Under certain cases, it seems that *sudo* confuses that sign for setting and environment variable.

I see this in sudo(8) man:

`Environment variables to be set for the command may also be passed on the command line in the form of VAR=value...`

This is a problem for me, for example, if I try to run a command like:

`sudo  -i  "cd /tmp; /usr/bin/hadoop fs -D dfs.replication=2 -ls"`

It actually goes into a root shell instead of executing the command, since the command is misinterpreted.
I see this in *sudo.log*:

`Apr 29 16:11:40 : my_user : TTY=pts/7 ; PWD=/home/my_user ; USER=root ; ENV=cd /tmp; /usr/bin/hadoop fs -D dfs.replication=2 -ls ; COMMAND=/bin/bash`

As you can see, the command is actually misinterpreted as trying to set ENV.

If I remove the preceeding `cd /tmp;` it will work. However, for some of my stuff, I have to run a *cd* command or something similar first.

This seems to be because of the equal sign which causes *sudo* to think I'm setting ENV. If I remove the equal sign (i.e. remove `-D dfs.replication=2` ), then it works, and logged correctly:

`Apr 29 16:08:46 : my_user : TTY=pts/7 ; PWD=/home/my_user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/tcsh -c cd /tmp; /usr/bin/hadoop fs -ls`

So my question is: How do I escape this *=* character, and/or get sudo read the command as a whole command, instead of thinking an equal sign is setting an environment variable?

Thanks much!

Comment: cd /tmp; sudo blah blah ?

Comment: I'd try the usual double-dash `--` to stop parsing command line arguments first: `sudo -i -- "cd /tmp; /usr/bin/hadoop fs -D dfs.replication=2 -ls"` (I've no system with sudo install at hand so that I could test it myself). If it's working I'm happily write an answer.

Comment: mclex -- good idea, but for some commands I need the `cd` to be in sudo, as non-privileged user won't be able to access the directory otherwise.

Comment: mpy -- I haven't tested your idea thoroughly (since I already went with daBeamer's answer below), but with a simple test it seems to also work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try *executing* a shell command via `sudo` rather than passing one directly. For example, do something like:

```
sudo bash -c "cd /root; ls -al"
```

Of course, this is a silly example since one could simply execute `sudo ls -al /root`, but hopefully it gets the point across.

*Executing* a shell command is much more explicit than passing one to `sudo` using the `-i` flag since that will execute the shell assigned to the `root` user on a given system. Furthermore, any potential issues with login resource files of the `root` user are avoided.

Bash (or your preferred shell) should parse out the `=` character properly. I went ahead and tested this on my end for completeness and didn't encounter any issues. If not, however, just escape the `=` by prefacing it with a `\` character.

Comment: Not sure why I haven't though of it, but it works! Thanks :)